# How to make a silver letter with a gold stroke like this one

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

Is anyone able to help me make a lowercase letter "n" like the attached?

[image]

Comment: Welcome Joe! Please share what you have tried and where it is failing. This is not a "tutorial on demand" site. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure of precise settings and it would take a lot of experimentation to replicate exactly, but it could be done with various combinations of layer effects including bevel and emboss, contours, and stroke. Play around and you are sure to get something similar.

This example uses two text layers containing the letter D, with various bevel and emboss effects on each layer, in addition to a stroke effect on one layer for the gold colour.

[image]

Comment: I added this answer as I don't think the duplicate question is quite an exact duplicate. Hopefully it will help the OP.